# One to one function defined in $\mathbb{R}+$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, continuity

Let $f:\mathbb{R}+\to f(\mathbb{R}+)$ such that $f$ is continous, strictly increasing, $f(0)=0$ and $$f(x+y)\le f(x)+f(y)\,,\quad \forall x,y\in \mathbb{R}+.$$

Could you please help me to prove that f is one to one and that its inverse is continuous?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean strictly increasing? Otherwise the identically zero function is a solution. Does $\Bbb +$ include $0$?

Comment: yes I mean strictly increasing

Comment: @Ben Since $f$ is increasing (I assume strictly increasing), it has an inverse and, being continuous, the inverse is also continuous. Is your problem to show that an increasing function is one-to-one? The proposed inequality does not seem to have a role here.

Comment: Or maybe your problem is to show that the range of $f$ is $\mathbb{R}_0^+$?

Comment: $f$ being continuous, I don't kow how to prove that its inverse is also continuous.